# automate excel file processing in perl and avoid dialog/UI interactions

Tags: perl, excel, automation, dialog, ole

How can a I guarantee that no pop-up dialogs will appear when I automate Microsoft Excel through OLE? I'm using a Perl module (Win32::OLE). I can avoid most dialog pop-ups using the following code:

```
use Win32::OLE;
use Win32::OLE::Variant;
use Win32::OLE::Const;

my $excel_symbols = Win32::OLE::Const->Load('Microsoft Excel');
my $excel = Win32::OLE->new('Excel.Application', sub { $_[0]->Quit();} );
$excel->{'Visible'} = 0;
$excel->{'DisplayAlerts'} = 0;
$excel->Workbooks->Open('c:\some_excel_file.xls',
  { 'UpdateLinks' => $excel_symbols->{'xlUpdateLinksNever'},
    'ReadOnly' => 1,
    'IgnoreReadOnlyRecommended' => 1
  });
```

However for some files, I continue to get a dialog with the following text:

> This file is not a recognizable
>   format.
>
> - If you know the file is from another program which is incompatible with
>     Microsoft Excel, click Cancel, then
>     open this file in its original
>     application. If you want to open the
>     file later in Microsoft Excel, save it
>     in a format that is compatible, such
>     as text format.
> - If you suspect the file is damaged, click Help for more information about
>     solving the problem.
> - If you still want to see what text is contained in the file, Click OK.
>     Then click Finish in the Text Import
>     Wizard.
>
> OK Cancel

Sometimes a similar dialog appears that contains 'OK', 'Cancel' and 'Help' buttons.

I cannot control the quality of files that are provided to the scripts.

Comment: It has been 3 or 4 days since the last incident involving a dialog box. I have to believe that something was incorrect in my original statements. Perhaps an Excel instance was corrupted?
If a new incident occurs, I will revisit the topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I revisited this issue and found a solution.

Copy the file before processing to a temporary location. Then save the file before closing it in Excel:

```
File::Copy::copy('c:\some_excel_file.xls', 'c:\temp\SFO3jfd.xls');
my $book = $excel->Workbooks->Open('c:\temp\SFO3jfd.xls',
  { 'UpdateLinks' => $excel_symbols->{'xlUpdateLinksNever'},
    'ReadOnly' => 1,
    'IgnoreReadOnlyRecommended' => 1
  });
$book->Save();
$book->Close();
```

**Why this works:**

Excel 2003 automatically recalculates the formulas in documents that were created in an older version of Excel. Furthermore, macros could be invoked when the document is opened. All of this means that there could be changes made on a document, even though your script doesn't perform any such operations.

By saving the document before closing, you avoid the dialog requesting that you save the file. Using a temporary file ensures that the original file does not get changed during the validation operation. If you aren't concerned about this, you might consider validating in-place.

Answer (score 3):

You could consider using [Spreadsheet::ParseExcel](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Spreadsheet-ParseExcel/lib/Spreadsheet/ParseExcel.pm) (albeit it may lack features you need) or [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/) (albeit it will need some wrapping to use in a Perl script) instead of calling the Excel engine over OLE. That way you won't get any Excel-generated dialogs.

Comment: There are two reason I didn't do this:
1. Spreadsheet::ParseExcel is not as fully featured as MS Excel.
2. Spreadsheet::ParseExcel is extremely slow for very large Excel spreadsheets.

Comment: I don't use Apache POI because we don't currently use java in our development.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa195811(office.11).aspx) is full documentation for Open method. I wonder if CorruptLoad  parameter is what you need.

Comment: CorruptLoad indicates different behavior depending on how many attempts have been made to load a file. The default behavior appears applicable in my case.

Answer (score -2):

If you are trying of process all xl files in the tree, some of them may be open by other users and have the ~ prefix.