# Exporting data from email body into outlook

Tags: excel, vba, email, outlook, export-to-excel

I regularly get consistently formatted emails with data which I'd like to extract for storage in microsoft dynamics CRM. I believe the easiest way to do this is to use VBA to take it into excel and then autohotkey to transfer it into the web form.

So far I have the following code to extract the data from the email but I'm having problems with extraneous line breaks and would like some feedback.

The data is as follows

```
Hi there, hope you are ok, lead is below.

-----Original Message-----
From: header waffle

The lead came through from the Lead Source: WEB FORM.
Date Received via Web: 10/10/2014 8:59 AM

Lead Information:

Their interests are: Orion water analysis instruments, Orion&trade; pH Electrode Filling Solution

blablabla 

Name: Joe Bloggs
Company: Generic Co.
Address:
line 1 line 2
Line 3 line 4
United Kingdom

Phone:  
Email: email@address.com 

Lead Notes: REF#:300100229
SKU:9003011
QTY:1
Customer Comments: 

ELMS ID: 00Q131M4f9vEAB

If you have any questions about this message, please contact me

Thank you.
```

I based the code on this [VBA Outlook. Trying to extract specific data from email body and export to Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22546918/vba-outlook-trying-to-extract-specific-data-from-email-body-and-export-to-excel) but because I am handling more data which is not on concurrent lines it has become hacky, especially because of all the extra line returns. How can I strip the data to be just what I want, and is there a nicer way to handle the multiple fragments of data?

The code is as follows:

```
Sub Extract()
    On Error GoTo 0
    Set myOlApp = Outlook.Application
    Set mynamespace = myOlApp.GetNamespace("mapi")

     Dim ThermoMail As Outlook.MailItem
    Set ThermoMail = Application.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem

    'open the current folder, I want to be able to name a specific folder if possible…
'Set myfolder = myOlApp.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder

    Set xlobj = CreateObject("excel.application.14")
    xlobj.Visible = True
    xlobj.Workbooks.Add
    'Set Headings

    xlobj.Range("A" & 1).Value = "Date Received via Web"
    xlobj.Range("A" & 2).Value = "Their interests are"
    xlobj.Range("A" & 3).Value = "Name"
    xlobj.Range("A" & 4).Value = "Company"
    xlobj.Range("A" & 5).Value = "Address"
    xlobj.Range("A" & 6).Value = "Phone"
    xlobj.Range("A" & 7).Value = "Email" '
    xlobj.Range("A" & 8).Value = "Lead Notes"
    xlobj.Range("A" & 9).Value = "SKU"
    xlobj.Range("A" & 10).Value = "QTY"
    xlobj.Range("A" & 11).Value = "Customer Comments"

    xlobj.Range("A" & 11).Value = ""

    Dim msgText As String
    msgText = ThermoMail.Body

    'search for specific text

    Dim delimtedMessage, Delim1 As String
    Delim1 = "###"

    delimtedMessage = Replace(delimtedMessage, "Date Received via Web:", "Delim1")
    delimtedMessage = Replace(delimtedMessage, "Their interests are:", "Delim1")
    delimtedMessage = Replace(msgText, "Purchasing Timeframe:", "Delim1")
    delimtedMessage = Replace(msgText, "Name:", "Delim1")
    delimtedMessage = Replace(delimtedMessage, "Company:", "Delim1")
    delimtedMessage = Replace(delimtedMessage, "Address:", "Delim1")
    delimtedMessage = Replace(delimtedMessage, "Phone:", "Delim1")
    delimtedMessage = Replace(delimtedMessage, "Email:", "Delim1")
    delimtedMessage = Replace(delimtedMessage, "Lead Notes:", "Delim1")
    delimtedMessage = Replace(delimtedMessage, "SKU:", "Delim1") '
    delimtedMessage = Replace(delimtedMessage, "QTY:", "Delim1")
    delimtedMessage = Replace(delimtedMessage, "Customer Comments:", "Delim1")
    delimtedMessage = Replace(delimtedMessage, "ELMS", "Delim1") 'everything after this should be discarded


    messageArray = Split(delimtedMessage, "Delim1")

    'write to excel
    'xlobj.Range("B" & 1).Value = messageArray(0) intentionally discarded
    xlobj.Range("B" & 1).Value = Trim(messageArray(1))
    xlobj.Range("B" & 2).Value = Trim(messageArray(2))
    xlobj.Range("B" & 3).Value = Trim(messageArray(3))
    xlobj.Range("B" & 4).Value = Trim(messageArray(4))
    xlobj.Range("B" & 5).Value = messageArray(5)
    xlobj.Range("B" & 6).Value = messageArray(6)
    xlobj.Range("B" & 7).Value = messageArray(7)
    xlobj.Range("B" & 8).Value = messageArray(8)
    xlobj.Range("B" & 9).Value = messageArray(9)
    xlobj.Range("B" & 10).Value = messageArray(10)
    xlobj.Range("B" & 11).Value = messageArray(11)

    End Sub
```

Comment: First this will fail: `xlobj.Range("A" & 1).Value`, then `delimtedMessage` is never initialized before use, so everything is `""`. Also you should remove the " for Delim1 so `Replace(delimtedMessage, "Date Received via Web:", Delim1)` and `Split(delimtedMessage, Delim1)`. I would Split the body with vbCrLf instead.

Answer (score 0):

Extracting from structured text is described here.

http://www.outlookcode.com/codedetail.aspx?id=89

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492012(v=office.12).aspx#Outlook2007ProgrammingCh17_ParsingTextFromAMessageBody

Demo:

```
Sub Extract2()

    Dim objItem As Object
    Dim intLocAddress As Integer
    Dim intLocCRLF As Integer

    Dim strArray(11) As String

    Set objItem = Application.ActiveInspector.currentItem

    If objItem.Class = olMail Then

        strArray(0) = ParseTextLinePair(objItem.body, "Date Received via Web:")
        Debug.Print "Date Received via Web: " & strArray(0)

        strArray(1) = ParseTextLinePair(objItem.body, "Their interests are:")
        Debug.Print "Their interests are: " & strArray(1)

        strArray(2) = ParseTextLinePair(objItem.body, "Purchasing Timeframe:")
        Debug.Print "Purchasing Timeframe: " & strArray(2)

        strArray(3) = ParseTextLinePair(objItem.body, "Name:")
        Debug.Print "Name: " & strArray(3)

        strArray(4) = ParseTextLinePair(objItem.body, "Company:")
        Debug.Print "Company: " & strArray(4)

        strArray(5) = ParseTextLinePair(objItem.body, "Address:")
        Debug.Print "Address: " & strArray(5)

        strArray(6) = ParseTextLinePair(objItem.body, "Phone:")
        Debug.Print "Phone: " & strArray(6)

        strArray(7) = ParseTextLinePair(objItem.body, "Email:")
        Debug.Print "Email: " & strArray(7)

        strArray(8) = ParseTextLinePair(objItem.body, "Lead Notes:")
        Debug.Print "Lead Notes: " & strArray(8)

        strArray(9) = ParseTextLinePair(objItem.body, "SKU:")
        Debug.Print "SKU: " & strArray(9)

        strArray(10) = ParseTextLinePair(objItem.body, "QTY:")
        Debug.Print "QTY: " & strArray(10)

    End If

    Set objItem = Nothing

End Sub

Function ParseTextLinePair(strSource As String, strLabel As String)
    Dim intLocLabel As Integer
    Dim intLocCRLF As Integer
    Dim intLenLabel As Integer
    Dim strText As String

    ' locate the label in the source text
    intLocLabel = InStr(strSource, strLabel)
    intLenLabel = Len(strLabel)
        If intLocLabel > 0 Then
        intLocCRLF = InStr(intLocLabel, strSource, vbCrLf)
        If intLocCRLF > 0 Then
            intLocLabel = intLocLabel + intLenLabel
            strText = Mid(strSource, _
                            intLocLabel, _
                            intLocCRLF - intLocLabel)
        Else
            intLocLabel = Mid(strSource, intLocLabel + intLenLabel)
        End If
    End If
    ParseTextLinePair = Trim(strText)
End Function
```