# Extracting the data from an outlook email

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

Been looking around for code to play with, but to no avail. I tried [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22546918/vba-outlook-trying-to-extract-specific-data-from-email-body-and-export-to-excel), really do not wish to go through it one by one.

I have an Email body that has lots of stuff to extract, difference is unlike the mail in the link there is no colon to help split them up.

```
Applicant   :   XXX XXXX XXXX

Approving Officer   :   XXX XXX XXXX

Applicant, Your leave application has been approved/rejected. Please view the status.

From        To          Leave Type              Full/1.5D/AM/PM                     Duration    Status              Covering Officer    
----------  ----------  ----------------------  --------------------------------    --------    ------------------  ------------------ 
DD/MM/YYYY  DD/MM/YYYY  Family Leave            FULL                                1           Leave Approved
```

What you see here is a generated email by the system. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The Outlook object model provides three different ways for working with item bodies:

1. Body - a plain text.
2. HTMLBody - an HTML markup.
3. The Word Editor. Outlook uses Word as an email editor, so you can use it to format the email message. The [WordEditor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868196(v=office.15).aspx) property of the Inspector class returns an instance of the Document class which represents the message body.

You can read more about all these ways in the [Chapter 17: Working with Item Bodies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492012%28v=office.12%29.aspx) in MSDN.